# VSTO : Open a Word document which is located in another directory than the VSTO file

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, clickonce

I'm quite sure that my question is such a tip but I could not find any solutions.

I have a Word Add-In solution in which I want to open a Word document which is not at the same directory as the vsto file.

Here is my code to open a word file :

```
object filename = Globals.ThisDocument.workingDirectory + Globals.ThisDocument.Id.ToString() + Constants.EXTENSION;
object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
Document doc = Globals.ThisDocument.Application.Documents.Open(ref filename, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
```

In my example : .vsto file is located in `bin/debug` and my word document in `bin/debug/save`

But I got this error :

Failed to load .vsto file

Sure, cause the .vsto file is not  in the same place than the word document ! ...

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: Did you try viewing the values of filename and missing through debugging windows? Use Watch windows and see what you get in these two.

Comment: Do you have a **Save** folder in your project with the word document added with its **Copy to Output directory** property set to `Copy Always`? If not - then you need to so that the project output is added to the Click-Once deployment. You can't manually add a folder to the `Debug` folder and expect it to be included in the deployment.

Comment: @SliverNinja It is not the problem, in fact, I want to open a document with code which is in an other folder than the initial document and the .vsto file but I got this error, got it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the answer by myself,

In fact when a document is saved in VSTO C# code, location of vsto file is stored in Word Xml structure.

So nevermind your docx are stored, they will find their vsto file.